# Python merging an aggregated grouped by dataframe and keeping all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes,
One is an aggregated, grouped by dataframe:

```
groupedby_df1= df.groupby(['Location', 'ID', 'X','Y','Z','C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'])
```

And another grouped by dataframe, but only with one level aggregation:

```
groupedby_df2= df.groupby(['ID'])
```

I have merged the two dataframes:

```
merged_df= pd.merge(groupedby_df1, groupedby_df2, how='left', on='ID')
```

My problem is that the merged dataframe only keeps the 'ID' column.
Is there any way i could have the same columns as in my "groupedby_df1".
same as in SQL left join, just add the information from groupedby_df2 on the right?

Thanks.

**groupedby_df1:**

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Sum_Consumption</th>
      <th>Avg_Shortage_Sim</th>
      <th>Avg_Buying_Price</th>
      <th>Count_days</th>
      <th>Avg_Shortage_R</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>C1</th>
      <th>C2</th>
      <th>C3</th>
      <th>C4</th>
      <th>C5</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5" valign="top">802003</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">254483014238</th>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>YES</th>
      <th>JEANS</th>
      <th>JEANS</th>
      <th>38</th>
      <th>0.0</th>
      <th>0.0</th>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1.0</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>YES</th>
      <th>YES</th>
      <th>YES</th>
      <th>JEANS</th>
      <th>JEANS</th>
      <th>38</th>
      <th>0.0</th>
      <th>0.0</th>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>0.0</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**groupedby_df2:**

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Sum_Consumption</th>
      <th>count_SKU</th>
      <th>Avg_Buying_Price</th>
      <th>Avg_Shortage_R</th>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>254483014236</th>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>0.000000</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>254483014238</th>
      <td>16.0</td>
      <td>1943</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>0.109624</td>
      
    </tr>
    
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the merged DF only gives me the ID column without all the other aggregated fields of groupedby_df1.

Comment: Tried to reproduce but got error `ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>`.

Comment: You must use aggregation after groupby operation. So, you can try this: ```groupedby_df2= df.groupby(['ID']).sum()``` and ```groupedby_df1= df.groupby(['Location', 'ID', 'X','Y','Z','C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']).sum()```

Comment: by the looks of it you are trying to merge `Grouper` objects. Instead, what `agg` operation do you need to perform after grouping?

Comment: yes, i alread used aggregation after grouping by.
im not getting any errorss, the merging is ok, just not how i would want it to merge.

Comment: im using different aggregation functions:
groupedby_df1= groupedby_df1.agg({'Consumption':'sum', 'ShortageDaySimulation':'mean','BuyingPrice':'mean', 'Date':'nunique', 'ShortageDayReality': 'mean', 'Buffer':'nunique', 'min_available_days':'mean'})

Comment: can you please post the sample dataframes and an expected output to avoid any confusion. :) Thanks

Comment: I have edited the questions above. hope it will make more sense.